# Supervisord does not work

Tags: server, supervisor

Yesterday, I reboot my Ubuntu 16.04 server for OpenEdx platform. After rebooting, my server down. I found that out the problem is not working of supervisord.
When I run this command :

```
sudo service supervisord start
```

I take this error:

> Failed to start supervisord.service: Unit supervisord.service is masked.

When I run :

```
sudo service supervisor restart
```

I get

> Job for supervisor.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status supervisor.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Running this: `systemctl status supervisor.service`

```
Failed to start supervisord.service: Unit supervisord.service is masked.
root@ip-:/# sudo service supervisord startFailed to start supervisord.service: Unit supervisord.service is masked.
supervisord: unrecognized service
root@ip-:/# sudo service supervisor restart
Job for supervisor.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status supervisor.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@ip-:/# sudo service supervisor restartJob for supervisor.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status supervisor.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.systemctl status supervisor.service
supervisor: unrecognized service
root@ip-:/# systemctl status supervisor.service
● supervisor.service - supervisord - Supervisor process control system
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/supervisor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-12-15 14:56:51 UTC; 1min 10s ago
     Docs: http://supervisord.org
  Process: 6546 ExecStart=/edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/bin/supervisord --configuration /edx/app/supervisor/supervisord.conf (code=exited, status=2)

Dec 15 14:56:51  systemd[1]: Starting supervisord - Supervisor process control system...
Dec 15 14:56:51  supervisord[6546]: Error: Cannot open an HTTP server: socket.error reported errno.EACCES (13)
Dec 15 14:56:51  supervisord[6546]: For help, use /edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/bin/supervisord -h
Dec 15 14:56:51  systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
Dec 15 14:56:51  systemd[1]: Failed to start supervisord - Supervisor process control system.
Dec 15 14:56:51  systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 15 14:56:51  systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I am using AWS for machine.

Comment: `supervisord` is not a standard Ubuntu package.  You'll have a faster response contacting AWS support on this.

Comment: @Fabby Amazon supporting for only premium users.Unfortuanlly i am under basic package

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that when Supervisord service won't run if, inside the /etc/supervisord.conf file, under the [include] header there's any .ini file, or even if the header itself is uncommented.

I had to start the service while this section is commented out, then once it's online, you can uncomment it and run:

```
supervisorctl update
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl reload
```